# Standing pools gather filth / dirt

Tags: expressions, proverbs, sayings

I am wondering whether the German proverb:

> Stehend Wasser stinkt.

Literal translation:

> Standing waters start to stink.

Makes sense in English.

I also came across an English version:

> - Standing pools gather filth / dirt.

I need to know if it makes sense to native speakers of English or it sounds to be a direct translation from another language?
Also, is there any more common way to imply the same message?

PS. The sentence (proverb) seems to be a kind of metaphor used to imply that human being needs to move and avoid being idle or inactive. We all need to try and those who stop due to any failure, fear, doubt, laziness etc. are condemned to stink like standing water.
I hope I could get the point across.
Please let me know if still there is something ambiguous.

Comment: We tend to focus on the opposite: a rolling stone gathers no moss.

Comment: The concept of [stagnant water](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stagnant) is of course well known, but I don't know of a proverb relating to it.

Comment: Thank you @KateBunting. Just does the sentence "stagnant waters stink" make a good sense and is it understandable by everyone?

Comment: It makes sense as a statement of fact, but I don't think everyone would understand it as a metaphor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The familiar proverb is "A rolling stone gathers no moss".  It means that a *person* who doesn't stay in one place will not gain many personal possessions.  (It used to be used proverbially to imply "And so you should stay in one place and prosper", but now is sometimes used to imply "And so you should keep moving and be free of having many belongings")

The literal meaning of "Standing waters stink" is clear enough.  It is not clear what the metaphor is supposed to imply:  "A person who doesn't change will become boring"  or is it about "systems that aren't updated become obsolete", or something else?  I'm not familiar with it as a proverb, and it doesn't appear in the phrases.org.uk list of proverbs, so it can't be common.